# PHP MySQL Queries - Addition

Tags: php, mysql, formulas

I am working on a formula where I am adding multiple values in a row and column depending on the values of other cells. For example I have the following working code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT School,SUM(Wins + Losses) as total FROM tennis GROUP BY School");
 echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>School</th>
<th>Score</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['School'] .  "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['total'] .  "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

However I want to add more columns that are also sums of other rows/columns and don't know how to do this while still keeping everything Grouped by the column 'School'. What I essentially want is the following, but the code is incorrect:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT School,SUM(Wins + Losses) as 1sttotal FROM tennis WHERE Event='1st Singles', SUM(Wins + Losses) as 2ndtotal FROM tennis WHERE Event='2nd Singles' GROUP BY School");
 echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>School</th>
<th>1st Singles</th>
<th>2nd Singles</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['School'] .  "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['1sttotal'] .  "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['2ndtotal'] .  "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure the correct/optimal way to go about setting this up. Thanks

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the query you should use to get the 2 totals:

```
SELECT 
    School,
    SUM(IF(Event='1st Singles', Wins + Losses, 0)) as 1sttotal,
    SUM(IF(Event='2nd Singles', Wins + Losses, 0)) as 2ndtotal
FROM tennis 
GROUP BY School;
```

See how it adds according to the `event` columns? The trick is to pass a `WHERE` filter within the `SELECT` clause through conditional execution (`IF`)

Other possibility using `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT 
    School,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN Event='1st Singles' THEN Wins + Losses
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) as 1sttotal,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN Event='2nd Singles' THEN Wins + Losses
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) as 2ndtotal
FROM tennis 
GROUP BY School;
```

Comment: For some reason the 1st option given didn't work, but the Case statement did. Thank you so much, I added for more case statements using the code above and it works great. Thanks

Comment: maybe you have some cases where Event is null?